# Hide payment area when no shipping method available in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

how can I hide all information inside red box (Paypal,Credit Card,Term and Condition,Subscribe(mailchimp),proceed to Paypal button and Privacy policy) when no shipping method available in Woocommerce?

Thank you

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1jVt.jpg)

Comment: Can you give me the url? I believe it can be done with some simple css.

Comment: check this https://jeroensormani.com/enable-disable-payment-gateways-for-specific-shipping-methods/

Comment: function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
 $chosen_shipping_rates = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
 // When 'local delivery' has been chosen as shipping rate
 if ( ! in_array( 'local_delivery', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
  // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
  unset( $gateways['cod'] );
 endif;
 return $gateways;

Comment: I dont know what code to put to tell that no shipping, but I understand now how to hide Paypal and other